# How do you add a pause in a flow for artillery?

Tags: load-testing, artillery

Is there a way of injecting a 1 to 2 second pause within a flow for scenarios that are asynchrounous and immediately trying to get the value will fail unless it rested for a couple of seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `think` with the number of seconds you'd like to pause for. In this example we GET /first_thing, wait two seconds, then GET /second_thing.

```
  - name: "Thinkflow"
    flow:
      - get:
           url: "/first_thing"
      - think: 2
      - get:
           url: "/second_thing"
```

Comment: Where is that documented?

Comment: I derived it from:

https://artillery.io/docs/basic-concepts/#example-testing-an-e-commerce-api

They define step 4 as: `POST to the cart endpoint with the same id after pausing for 3 seconds` which gets turned into the following artillery code:      `- think: 3
      - post:
          url: "/cart"
          json:
            productId: "{{ id }}"`

I couldn't find where 'think' is explicitly documented as a pause.

Comment: is there a way to add a random delay between requests ?